# carousel full slider to specific item from external link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have index.html with anchors which i want to navigate to different items in houses.html. houses.html has full page carousel slider with 5 items ill paste only 2 of them.So to be clear inside index.html i have anchors which navigate to houses.html like this :

```
<li><a id="houses-slide-1" >Stark</a></li>
<li><a id="houses-slide-2" >Lannister</a></li>
```

and jquery for the anchors :

```
$('#houses-slide-1').click(function(){
            /*do something here maybe?*/
            window.location.href = 'sl/houses.html';
        });
        $('#houses-slide-2').click(function(){
            /*do something here maybe?*/
            window.location.href = 'sl/houses.html';
        });
```

houses.html HTML :

```
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" id="slide-one-1">
            <div class="item active">
                <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/ned.jpg');">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2 slide-paneli">
                            <div class="col-md-12  slide-paneli">
                             <a class="remove-session" href="../index.html"> <img class="back-img" src="img/back.png" alt="back button"></a>
                            </div>                            
                            <h1>...</h1>
                            <p>...</p>                           
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Starks</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" id="slide-two-2">
                <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/cersei.jpg');">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2 slide-paneli">                           
                            <div class="col-md-12  slide-paneli">
                                 <a class="remove-session" href="../index.html"> <img class="back-img" src="img/back.png" alt="back button"></a>
                            </div>
                            <h1>...</h1>
                            <p>...</p>
                            <div class="row">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Lannister</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. And why would you use jQuery to navigate between pages instead of the `href` property of anchor tags?

Comment: because i tried to pass data between pages and on page load jquery click on the corausel next buttons

Comment: .click method is jquery method

Comment: Sure, but then formulate a question.

Comment: The question is clear i have anchors in page which must lead to different sections/items in houses.html otherwise the houses.html is opened always at the first slider and  i want to navigate to second third and so on sliders from external link

Answer (score 0):

Change your jQuery to “load” the new page at the ID you want:

```
$('#houses-slide-1').click(function() {
    window.location.href = 'sl/houses.html#slide-one-1';
});

$('#houses-slide-2').click(function() {
    window.location.href = 'sl/houses.html#slide-two-2';
});
```

Of course this is a terrible solution. You will have to update every `click` handler every time you change the ID of the slides.

Comment: tried this its not working still dont know why but this was the first thing i tried